# Why would the 2+ molecular ion of butane have a mass spectrum peak at 29?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Question 7 of Edexcel's June 2014 Unit 2 exam paper reads:

> In a mass spectrum of butane, C4H10, where would a peak be seen for
>   the molecular ion if it had a charge of 2+?

The answer is 29.

My question is: why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mass spectrometer observes the mass to charge ratio (*m*/*z*). Most of the time, small organic molecules like butane will be singly charged by the ionizer, which means that the mass can be read off directly since *z* =1.

If butane was somehow ionized to the +2 state, then the mass spec would observe 58/2=29, which is the mass of butane (58 g/mol) divided by the charge (+2).

This becomes particularly important for larger compounds with multiple easily ionizable groups, such as peptides. A series of peaks corresponding to different charge states can be used to identify the compound of interest.